Lower bound of Frobenius inner product
Consider $A,B$ are $n\times n$ matrices.
It is known that the Frobenius inner product can be upper bounded as $$\langle A,B \rangle_F \leq \|A\|_2\|B\|_F$$
What about the lower bound?

please explain the downvoted

Since the Frobenius inner product is just the sum of the column vectors' dot products (or row vectors'), then we could find a lower bound if we found something that relates 'features' of the matrices to a lower bound for the dot product. There is nothing in terms of the norms of the matrices, or norms of the individual row or column vectors. In other words, with such limited information as the norm, the lower bound is
$0$. (I'm assuming you don't know anything specific about the entries of $A$ and $B$, and you are referring to a lower bound in absolute value.)

could also be negative right?

Right, I meant in absolute value. If you want the signed lower bound, then it's minus the upper bound.
